# Как обработать "Открыть с помощью" в python файле?

Tags: python, windows, файлы

Всем привет. Недавно задумался, каким образом можно обработать виндовсный "Открыть с помощью" python файлом. Я хочу написать программу, которая будет принимать файл именно таким образом, после чего уже работать с ним. В интернете информации об этом не нашел, но помню как делал так с каким-то плагином несколько лет назад. Что я имею в виду:

[image: Пример]

Может кто-то подсказать, как реализовать этот код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таким образом передаётся путь файла, получить её можно таким образом

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[1]) # Тут будет полный путь к файлу с которым вы сделали "Открыть с помощью"
# sys.argv[2] sys.argv[3] и тд если вы перетащите несколько файлов
```